# how to highlight selected item in multiple ionic lists?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have three ionic lists and 2nd one get data while selecting first one and 3rd one gets data while selecting 2nd.
I want to highlight the selected item in all 3 lists.

can someone help here

```
        <ion-row align-items-start>
          <ion-col>
            <ion-grid class="gridStyle">
              <ion-row align-items-start>
                <ion-col>
                  <ion-scroll style="height:200px" scrollY="true">
                    <ion-list>
                      <button ion-item *ngFor="let route of Routes" (click)="selectCP(route.ID)">
                        {{route.Name}}
                      </button>
                    </ion-list>
                  </ion-scroll>
                </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            <!--Collection Points-->
            <ion-grid class="gridStyle">
              <ion-row align-items-start>
                <ion-col>
                  <ion-scroll style="height:200px" scrollY="true">
                    <div *ngIf="hideCPmsg" style="color: rgb(168, 163, 163);"> Select a route to see collection points</div>
                    <div *ngIf="hideCPnotfound" style="color: red;"> No collection points found!</div>
                    <ion-list scroll="true">
                      <button ion-item *ngFor="let colpoint of CPs" (click)="selectAsset(colpoint.ID)" >
                        {{colpoint.Name}}
                      </button>
                    </ion-list>
                  </ion-scroll>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col>
            <ion-grid class="gridStyle">
              <ion-row align-items-start>
                <ion-col>
                  <ion-scroll style="height:200px" scrollY="true">
                    <ion-list>
                      <button ion-item *ngFor="let asset of Assets">
                        {{route.Name}}
                      </button>
                    </ion-list>
                  </ion-scroll>
                </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
          </ion-col>
       </ion-row>
```

This is  the .ts file skeleton structure  with sample data structure

This is  the .ts file skeleton structure  with sample data structure

```
export class HierarchyPage{
  Routes:any[];
  CPs:any[];
  Assets:any[];

  constructor(public navCtrl:NavController){}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.Routes = [
      {"ID":"938","Name":"4050001 - ANDREWS RTE 1"}, 
      {"ID":"936","Name":"4050002 - ANDREWS RTE 2"}
    ];
  }

  selectRoute() {
    this.CPs = [
      {"ID":"100","Name":"CPRTE 1"},
      {"ID":"101","Name":"CP 2"}
    ]
  }

  selectCP() {
    this.Assets = [
      {"ID":"450","Name":"ASSEt 1"},
      {"ID":"451","Name":"Asset2"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I've answered but just a question. You want to highlight ALL lists when selecting a item on the first list or you want to highlight each individual list item when they're selected? Either way if you want a better answer just post you .ts file so we kno what are the existing information

Comment: I want to highlight each individual list item when they are selected

Comment: export class HierarchyPage{
Routes:any[];CPs:any[];Assets:any[];

constructor(public navCtrl:NavController){}

ngOnInit()
{
this.Routes=[{"ID":"938","Name":"4050001 - ANDREWS RTE 1"},{"ID":"936","Name":"4050002 - ANDREWS RTE 2"}]
}
selectRoute(){
this.CPs=[{"ID":"100","Name":"CPRTE 1"},{"ID":"101","Name":"CP 2"}]
}
selectCP(){
this.Assets=[{"ID":"450","Name":"ASSEt 1"},{"ID":"451","Name":"Asset2"}]
}}

Comment: Put this code in your question please

Comment: updated question with .ts

Comment: Thanks, updated answer, this should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) to highlight the button if they have the same ID. You need to create a class for this

your-page.css

```
.hightlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

In your .ts file i'm assuming you have some properties in your class for the selected route, cp and asset

```
public selectedRoute; // the id of your selected route
public selectedCp; // the id of your selected route
public selectedAsset; // the id of your selected route
```

And in your lists:

```
<ion-row align-items-start>
          <ion-col>
            <ion-grid class="gridStyle">
              <ion-row align-items-start>
                <ion-col>
                  <ion-scroll style="height:200px" scrollY="true">
                    <ion-list>
                      <button ion-item *ngFor="let route of Routes" (click)="selectCP(route.ID)" [ngClass]="{'highlight': route.id === selectedId}">
                        {{route.Name}}
                      </button>
                    </ion-list>
                  </ion-scroll>
                </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            <!--Collection Points-->
            <ion-grid class="gridStyle">
              <ion-row align-items-start>
                <ion-col>
                  <ion-scroll style="height:200px" scrollY="true">
                    <div *ngIf="hideCPmsg" style="color: rgb(168, 163, 163);"> Select a route to see collection points</div>
                    <div *ngIf="hideCPnotfound" style="color: red;"> No collection points found!</div>
                    <ion-list scroll="true">
                      <button ion-item *ngFor="let colpoint of CPs" (click)="selectAsset(colpoint.ID)" [ngClass]="{'highlight': colpoint.id === selectedCp}">
                        {{colpoint.Name}}
                      </button>
                    </ion-list>
                  </ion-scroll>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col>
            <ion-grid class="gridStyle">
              <ion-row align-items-start>
                <ion-col>
                  <ion-scroll style="height:200px" scrollY="true">
                    <ion-list>
                      <button ion-item *ngFor="let asset of Assets" [ngClass]="{'highlight': asset.id === selectedAsset}">
                        {{route.Name}}
                      </button>
                    </ion-list>
                  </ion-scroll>
                </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
          </ion-col>
       </ion-row>
```

This should do, if your selected route/asset/cp is equal to the id of the item in the `ngFor` it'll set the `highlight` class to the item

Hope this helps.